# Obtaining logical lists of Bloomberg security codes in Excel

Tags: derivatives, bloomberg, excel

I am using Bloomberg's BDP and BDH functions in excel to retrieve data for a set of options.

The problem is that (as underlying prices move and expiration dates come and go) option strikes are constantly being created.  Rather than setting up a list of all possible strikes and concatenating my option codes, I would like to be able to "ask" Bloomberg for all the valid option codes in a certain category.

By doing this I can be sure I did not miss any and possibly save some time when fetching data for many instruments.

Is there a simple way to populate a list of securities (stocks, futures, options, options on futures, etc.) from Bloomberg based on categories?

Here is a crude example of what I mean:  '=BSECURITY("Commodity", "Interest Rate", "Treasuries", "Future-Options", DATE)

Comment: I recommend to first send your question to the Bloomberg helpdesk, just post it into their chat.

Comment: agree with emcor; would recommend also to check if XLTP <go> have some excel templates for options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BBPlus, and help desk, I found out this is possible.

From terminal XLTP XLOP.  Download the XLOP spreadsheet. From "Single Options" tab you can see a great example of how to use BBOPT() function to pull a list of feed codes.